# Como mostrar postagem completa ao clicar no botão ler tudo?

Tags: php

Eu estou criando um blog e gostaria de saber como fazer o seguinte.:

Na página inicial eu exibo o titulo, uma imagem e um resumo da postagem, e ao clicar no botão "Ler Tudo", a postagem seja aberta por completo em outra janela do navegador, como em blogs da internet.

Estou desenvolvendo da seguinte forma: Fiz todo o layout de um site para um negócio da minha cidade, mais exatamente uma loja de materiais para construção, e também foi pedido um portal de notícias.

Eu apenas estou realizando testes em um projeto externo, antes de incorporar ao código do site. Vou postar o código para que vocês possam ver. Sou muito leigo com PHP,estou utilizando o Notepad++ para desenvolver meu código.

```
<?php require( 'conectar.php') ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Blog</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php $sql=m ysql_query( " SELECT * FROM postagem ORDER BY data DESC"); $conta=m ysql_num_rows($sql); if($conta <=0 ){ echo '<h2>Nenhuma postagem encontrada.</h2>'; }else{ while($res=m ysql_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
        <div class="postagem"> <span> <h2><a><?php echo $res['titulo']; ?></a></h2> </span>  <span> <h3><a><?php echo $res['postagem']; ?></a></h3> </span> 
        </div>
        <?php }} ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Encontrei a seguinte função.:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
global $post;
return ‘… <a href=”‘. get_permalink($post->ID) . ‘”>’ . ‘Ler matéria completa &raquo;’ . ‘</a>’;
}
add_filter(‘excerpt_more’, ‘new_excerpt_more’);
```

Eu conseguiria aplicá-la a minha necessidade?

Comment: Luis, a sua pergunta não é relacionada com php, pelo menos não somente. Pode explicar melhor que blog têm e como pode alterar/criar HTML nessa página? ou quer fazer o redirecionamento no php mudando o `header`?

Comment: Luis, precisamos de mais informações para poder ajuda-lo. Você está fazendo esse blog todo do zero, sem framework? Já tentou alguma coisa? Se sim poste o código.

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo da seguinte forma. Fiz todo o layout de um site para um negócio da minha cidade, mais exatamente uma loja de materiais para construção, e também foi pedido um portal de notícias. Eu apenas estou realizando testes em um projeto externo, antes de incorporar ao código do site. Vou postar o código para que vocês possam ver.
Sou muito leigo com PHP,estou utilizando o Notepad++ para desenvolver meu código.
Sérgio, fui incapaz de compreender sobre esse redirecionamento como disse e sobre a mudança no header.
Nem criei o botão Ler tudo, por não saber a estrutura necessária em PHP.

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, sou iniciante aqui no stackoverflow, fico grato pelas instruções.

Comment: Você está utilizando WordPress ou encontrou esta função pesquisando no Google?

Comment: @lfarroco, pensei que iria funcionar adaptando, encontrei no google, não uso wordpress.
Não está funcionando ainda, não consigo abrir a postagem completa. Poderia me ajudar com isso?
Encontrei este tutorial, mas não fui capaz de entender nada que foi explicado nele, apenas quero fazer como foi feito ai, quero mostrar todas as postagens resumidas no meu index.php, e abri-las quando clicado no botão Ler Tudo, em uma janela _blank com o mesmo design, só que com a postagem completa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não conheço a estrutura de seu projeto, mais vou tentar explicar.

Você possuí uma página onde exibe todas as postagens, nesta página, no título de cada postagem como em seu código, você adicionou um link que pode levar para outra página, passando como parâmetro o `id` da postagem que deve ser exibida, exemplo:

```
 <div class="postagem"> <span> 
  <h2>
     <a href="lerPostagem.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'];?>" title="ler postagem completa">
        <?php echo $res['titulo']; ?>
     </a>
  </h2>
```

Na página *lerPostagem.php*, você deve pegar o parâmetro `id` via [GET](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php) e selecionar a postagem em seu Banco de dados:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM postagem WHERE postagem.id = $id");
```

Com a postagem selecionada você pode exibi-la complemente nesta página.

**Obs:** É necessário tomar cuidados para evitar [injeção de SQL](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/security.database.sql-injection.php), considere utilizar prepare statements com [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php).

**Obs 2:** Esta é apenas uma explicação didática, existem N maneiras de fazer, seria preciso conhecer melhor seu projeto para aconselhá-lo melhor.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado, consegui compreender o que deve ser feito, eu sabia que isso devia ser feito, mas eu não sabia como fazer.